# Using spring beans in Quartz JobListener implementation

Tags: java, spring, autowired, quartz

I have a use case where have to store job state. For that implemented **JobListener**. Here is the implementation

```
@Component
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
   @AllArgsConstructor
public class JobStateListener implements JobListener {

private String name;

@Autowired
private JobRepo<AbstractJob> jobRepo;


@Autowired
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

@Autowired
private AbstractJobStateRepo abstractJobStateRepo;
public void setGlobalListenerName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

// Run this if job is about to be executed.
@Override
public void jobToBeExecuted(JobExecutionContext context) {
    findJobState(context);
}
// No idea when will run this?
@Override
public void jobExecutionVetoed(JobExecutionContext context) {
    findJobState(context);
}
// Run this after job has been executed
@Override
public void jobWasExecuted(JobExecutionContext context, JobExecutionException jobException) {
    findJobState(context);
}

private void findJobState(JobExecutionContext context) {
    String jobName = context.getJobDetail().getKey().toString();
    Trigger.TriggerState state = getJobState(jobName, context);
    updateJobState(jobName, state.name());
}


private Trigger.TriggerState getJobState(String jobName, JobExecutionContext context) {
    TriggerKey triggerKey = triggerKey(StringUtils.substringAfter(jobName, "."), "BA");
    Trigger.TriggerState state = null;
    try {
        state = context.getScheduler().getTriggerState(triggerKey);
    } catch (SchedulerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return state;
}

void updateJobState(String jobName, String state) {
    List<AbstractJob> jobs = jobRepo.findByJobNameAndDeleted(jobName, false);
    if (Objects.nonNull(jobs) && !CollectionUtils.isEmpty(jobs)) {
        long jobId = jobs.get(0).getId();
        List<AbstractJobState> abstractJobStates =
                abstractJobStateRepo.findByJobIdAndDeleted(jobId, false);
        abstractJobStateRepo.save( prepareJobStateObject(state, CollectionUtils.isEmpty(abstractJobStates) ? false : true,
                jobId));
    }
}

private AbstractJobState prepareJobStateObject(String state, boolean isUpdate, long jobId) {
    AbstractJobState abstractJobState = new AbstractJobState();
    abstractJobState.setState(state);
    if (isUpdate) {
        abstractJobState.setUpdatedDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
    } else {
        abstractJobState.setCreatedDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
    }
    abstractJobState.setJobId(jobId);
    abstractJobState.setDeleted(false);

    return abstractJobState;

}
```

}

Problem here is all the @Autowired beans are **null**

How can I inject beans ?

Comment: It seems that your class was not picked up by Spring. How do you configure your Spring application context? Are you using Spring Boot?

Comment: Yes we are using spring boot

Answer (score 1):

The Spring Boot autoconfiguration does not pick up the JobListener automatically. You can add this functionality by adding `SchedulerFactoryBeanCustomizer` like so (sorry for the Kotlin, I'm sure you can translate this to Java easily):

```
@Configuration
class JobListenerConfiguration {
    @Bean
    fun jobListenerSchedulerCustomizer(jobListeners: List<JobListener>): SchedulerFactoryBeanCustomizer {
        return SchedulerFactoryBeanCustomizer { schedulerFactoryBean -> schedulerFactoryBean.setGlobalJobListeners(*jobListeners.toTypedArray()) }
    }
}
```